# What is the Recommended RAM size for kafka brokers when we set up the clauster?

Tags: apache-kafka

Currently we are working to setup the Kafka cluster .Can you please let me know recommended Kafka broker's RAM size when we setup the cluster ?

Comment: Hardware recommendations are considered off topic for Stackoverflow, by the way, and this heavily depends on your workload unless you want to over-provision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka use efficiently the memory by directly writing to the page cache. 
You should consider at least 32Go of RAM per node (3 node min) it's enough to begin with a production cluster.

Do no forget to spin up a zookeeper ensemble too in different machines that the one use for Kafka. Zookeeper can work with less ram so 8Go per node it's enough but you should consider dedicated SSD disk for the transaction log of zookeeper, the rest can be hard disk either on Kafka or zookeeper.

Comment: Thanks for your Response